# \foreignlanguage,\begin{otherlanguage},\selectlanguage{english} in tabular environment

Tags: tables, babel

\foreignlanguage work in first test-tabular. [image]
But \foreignlanguage does not work in second tabular. How to switch language in tabular?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1  
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
Work:``We will implement prudent and responsible macroeconomic policies to ensure mutually reinforcing effect of growth and to maintain economic and financial stability in the region, and prevent negative spillover effect.''
\end{otherlanguage*}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.1\textwidth}|}
{\foreignlanguage{english}{Work: some words in english.}}& А здесь русское длинное слово. \\
5 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\scshape}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|}
\hline
\thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{ITF.LEV}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{english}{TRTUTBL, c}}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}TRTUTBL, c\end{otherlanguage}}}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{{\selectlanguage{english}TVTETBL, c\selectlanguage{russian}}}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVTUTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPCTBL, c}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{H1TBL}\textbf{, }\textbf{мор. миля}\textbf{2}\textbf{/c}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{DMODTBL, мор. миля}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVVTT\_TBL, с}
}}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\hline
\thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{ITF.LEV}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{english}{TRTUTBL, c}}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}TRTUTBL, c\end{otherlanguage}}}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{{\selectlanguage{english}TVTETBL, c\selectlanguage{russian}}}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVTUTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPCTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{H1TBL}\textbf{, }\textbf{мор. миля}\textbf{2}\textbf{/c}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{DMODTBL, мор. миля}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVVTT\_TBL, с}
}}\\ \hline 
\endhead
7
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 48
 & .004
 & 1.10
 & 40
 & 25
\\ \hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? Several  packages (at least `longtable` and `pdflscape`) seem to be missing. Also, where did you get the `g0019` package from?

Comment: @leandriis I tried to make my code compilable and add new simple table with \foreignlanguage. \foreignlanguage working in this table. 
I don’t understand anymore.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. In your first working example table, the cell "Work: some words in english."  contains proper english words so latex knows where to hyphenate. The econd table on the other hand contains no real words such as "TRTUTBL" . In addition to that, the first word of a paragraph (in your case the first word in a table cell)  will by default not be hyphenated.

Comment: Could you please also explain the reason for the rather complicated column width of `0.081818\textwidth` ?

Comment: Maybe you are more satisfied with a table on a portrait page but with 90° rotated column headers?

Comment: @leandriis the g0019 package is one of my style packages with settings for Tex. Column width for this table matched automatically to the width of the page. Maybe you're right. I will have to use a table with 90° rotated column headers. 
Thank you very much for the answer.
How automatically select the column height with 90° rotated column headers?

Comment: Instead of `\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|}` you might want to consider using `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|{10}{X}|}` (requires the `xltabular` package)  in order to get a long table that is as wide as the textwidth with 10 equally wide columns.

Comment: For rotated column headers I'd recommend the use of `\rothead` from the `makecell` package.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are satisfied with one of the following layouts:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell,rotating}
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\scshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\bfseries DMODTBL, мор. миля\quad}
\begin{longtable}{|*{10}{c|}}
\hline
\rothead{ITF.LEV} 
& \rothead{\foreignlanguage{english}{TRTUTBL, c}}
& \rothead{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}TRTUTBL, c\end{otherlanguage}} 
& \rothead{\selectlanguage{english}TVTETBL, c\selectlanguage{russian}}
& \rothead{TVTUTBL, с} 
& \rothead{TVPCTBL, c} 
& \rothead{H1TBL, мор. миля2c} 
& \rothead{DMODTBL, мор. миля} 
& \rothead{TVPETBL, с} 
& \rothead{TVVTT\_TBL, с}\\ \hline 
\endhead
7
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 48
 & .004
 & 1.10
 & 40
 & 25
\\ \hline 
\end{longtable} 


\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\bfseries TVPETBL, с\quad}
\begin{longtable}{|*{10}{c|}}
\hline
\rothead{ITF.LEV} 
& \rothead{\foreignlanguage{english}{TRTUTBL, c}}
& \rothead{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}TRTUTBL, c\end{otherlanguage}} 
& \rothead{\selectlanguage{english}TVTETBL, c\selectlanguage{russian}}
& \rothead{TVTUTBL, с} 
& \rothead{TVPCTBL, c} 
& \rothead{H1TBL, мор. миля2c} 
& \rothead{DMODTBL, мор. миля} 
& \rothead{TVPETBL, с} 
& \rothead{TVVTT\_ TBL, с}\\ \hline 
\endhead
7
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 48
 & .004
 & 1.10
 & 40
 & 25
\\ \hline 
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}
```